# MongoDB how to find multiple documents using $match

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this

```
{
 "name": "Sai Darshan"
}
{
 "name": "Sathya"
}
{
 "name": "Richie"
}
```

I want to match the documents with the name "Sathya" and "Richie".

How can I achieve this using `$match`.
I currently tried this

```
$db = $this->dbMongo->selectDB("userData");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("userObject");

$aggregationFields = [
      [
        '$match' => [
          'name'=> 'Sathya',
          'name'=> 'Richie',
        ]
      ]
 ];

$cursor = $collection->aggregate($aggregationFields)->toArray();
```

Currently I am getting only the document

```
{
 "name": "Richie"
}
```

I am expecting to fetch both documents i.e. the documents with the name "Sathya" and "Richie".
I expect to do this with $match itself because I have further pipelines I want to pass this data to.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Use $in to match options from array: `{$match: {name: {$in: ['Sathya', 'Richie']}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@nimrod serok answered in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73862828/mongodb-how-to-find-multiple-documents-using-match#comment130423585_73862828), which is to use [the `$in` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

What is probably happening in with the query in the description is that the driver is de-duplicating the `name` entry. So the query that the database receives only includes the filter for `'name'=> 'Richie'`. You can see some reference to that [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-field), and javascript itself will also demonstrate this behavior:

```
> filter = { name: 'Sathya', name: 'Richie' };
{ name: 'Richie' }
>
```